# LINQ Except method but for JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

Probably you know C# `Except()` method that from first collection deletes elements contained in second collection. I have to write analogic method but for JSON.

That's what I did:

```
public static JsonDocument Except(this JsonDocument firstJson, JsonDocument secondJson)
    {
        if (firstJson.RootElement.ValueKind != secondJson.RootElement.ValueKind)
            throw new JsonException($"The '{nameof(firstJson)}' and '{nameof(secondJson)}' must be the same kind of value");

        switch (firstJson.RootElement.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                var result = JsonNode.Parse("{}")!;

                var firstJsonProperties = firstJson.RootElement.EnumerateObject();
                foreach (var firstJsonProperty in firstJsonProperties)
                {
                    if (!secondJson.RootElement.TryGetProperty(firstJsonProperty.Name, out JsonElement secondJsonPropertyValue)
                        || secondJsonPropertyValue.ValueKind != firstJsonProperty.Value.ValueKind)
                    {
                        result[firstJsonProperty.Name] = firstJsonProperty.Value.AsNode();
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (firstJsonProperty.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
                    {
                        var objectExceptionResult = Except(firstJsonProperty.Value.ToJsonDocument(), secondJsonPropertyValue.ToJsonDocument());
                        if (objectExceptionResult.RootElement.AsNode()!.AsObject().Any())
                            result[firstJsonProperty.Name] = objectExceptionResult.RootElement.AsNode();
                    }
                    else if (firstJsonProperty.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                    {
                        var arrayExceptionResult = Except(firstJsonProperty.Value.ToJsonDocument(), secondJsonPropertyValue.ToJsonDocument());
                        if (arrayExceptionResult.RootElement.AsNode()!.AsArray().Any())
                            result[firstJsonProperty.Name] = arrayExceptionResult.RootElement.AsNode();
                    }
                }

                return result.ToJsonDocument();

            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                var result2 = new JsonArray();

                var firstJsonElements = firstJson.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
                var secondJsonElements = secondJson.RootElement.EnumerateArray();

                foreach (var firstJsonElement in firstJsonElements)
                {
                    foreach (var secondJsonElement in secondJsonElements)
                    {
                        if (firstJsonElement.ValueKind != secondJsonElement.ValueKind)
                            continue;

                        if (firstJsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object || firstJsonElement.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                        {
                            var exceptionResult = Except(firstJsonElement.ToJsonDocument(), secondJsonElement.ToJsonDocument());
                            if (!firstJsonElement.IsEquivalentTo(exceptionResult.RootElement))
                            {
                                if (exceptionResult.RootElement.AsNode()!.AsObject().Any())
                                    result2.Add(exceptionResult);

                                break;
                            }
                            else if (secondJsonElement.IsEquivalentTo(secondJsonElements.Last()))
                            {
                                result2.Add(firstJsonElement);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (firstJsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Object && firstJsonElement.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Array
                    && !secondJsonElements.Any(p => p.ToString() == firstJsonElement.ToString()))
                        result2.Add(firstJsonElement);
                }

                return result2.ToJsonDocument();

            default:
                if (!firstJson.RootElement.IsEquivalentTo(secondJson.RootElement))
                    return firstJson;

                break;
        }

        return firstJson;
    }
```

This code is not beautiful. But there happens something worse. It sometimes doesn't work.

For simple JSON data like it:

```
var firstJson = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{
   ""x"":""haha"",
   ""a"":{
      ""z"":1,
      ""b"":3
   },
   ""haff"": [
     1,
     2,
    {
    ""a"": 4,
""b"": 5
}
    ]
}");

var secondJson = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{
   ""x"": 1024,
   ""b"":""afa"",
   ""a"":{
      ""z"":3,
      ""a"":4
   },
   ""haff"": [
     1,
     2,
    {
    ""a"": 5
}
    ]
}");
```

It works very well. But the bad things happens when both first and second JSONs are arrays and the first has less elements than second. Then not all appropriate elements are deleted from first JSON.

I really don't know why it happens. Do you have any ideas what goes wrong in this code? Or maybe you know ready to use NuGet packages that provides this functionality?

If you need more details, please comment my question.

NOTE: I use `Json.More.Net` NuGet package in this code.

Generally, the code shall:

1. If the property stores simple structure (string, int etc), so it's key-value pair, shall delete this property if it's also contained in second JSON
2. If the property stores array, then will delete from array all elements that are also contained in appropriate array in second JSON.
3. If the property stores object, then will delete properties from this object which are also contained in appropriate object in second JSON.
4. If all data is deleted from array or object, it also shall delete whole object or array.

That's result of calling `Except(firstJson, secondJson)` (variables defined above):

```
{
   "x":"haha",
   "a":{
      "b":3
   },
   "haff":[
      {
         "b":5
      }
   ]
}
```

When calling `Except(secondJson, firstJson)` (so I swapped firstJson with secondJson), result will look like this:

```
{
   "x":1024,
   "b":"afa",
   "a":{
      "a":4
   }
}
```

Seems easy, but remember that arrays can contain objects that contains another arrays that contains another objects etc.

Comment: Nobody is going to read your code. it is too much for this resource. If you need some code review there is a special forum here. So it is not clear from your question what are you trying to except in the case of array or object? the whole object or only the properties?

Comment: I added description about what code shall do. Btw I was at codereview forum and my question was deleted because it wasn't fully working code.

Comment: Thanks for jsons, but  I still don't understand what  do you want. Can you post a final json you are trying to get?

Comment: Are you comparing properties names or values?

Comment: I have edited my question. I'm comparing properties names and values. If property name matches, then I check if the data type which this property stores also matches.

Comment: Thanks, but pls change array integers, 3,4 for a second for example. Or if it will be string instead of int?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what should I change. In the second result there is only "a" property in "a" array, because the "z" was also contained in array from JSON from second function argument. Why do you think the values 3 and 4 could be string instead of int?

Comment: I mean what would be the result if you change 1,2 of second json array to 3,4  or add some primitive values?

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to mention about it. When arrays has simple values like "somestring", 1, 2, 3 I want to compare these values. So while we have 1,2 it's deleted, but when we change it to 3,4 in only one array, it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Why you didn't  remove x ? it is in both jsons.

Comment: Because it has different types. One is int (1024) and another one is string "haha"

Comment: a.z have different values 1 and 3 , why you remove them?

Comment: I remove property when the type of stored data and property name matches, value doesn't matter

Comment: Ok. I have done comparison for everything already , except Array  primitive values like numbers. Array values doesn't have any names, and can be in any order, it needs a different algorithm

Comment: I have used `IsEquivalentTo` from `Json.More` NuGet to do this. Foreach elements in array and check if there is any element in appropriate array from second JSON where `IsEquivalentTo` returns true. But maybe it is why my code is not always working?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't read your code. It is too much for me. I am trying to do it in my own way. :But I don't think any sense to use json library to compare array of string for example. It is a pure c# linq

Comment: And I am sure there are  libraries that can compare several jsons. For me it is just an exersice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use Newtonsoft.Json. This is my solution, this code is more clear for me

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var result = ExceptJsons(secondJsonString, firstJsonString);

public static JObject ExceptJsons(string firstJsonString, string secondJsonString)
{
    var firstJsonObj = JObject.Parse(firstJsonString);
    var secondJsonObj = JObject.Parse(secondJsonString);

    var fjp = GetPropPathes(firstJsonObj);
    var sjp = GetPropPathes(secondJsonObj);

    var result = fjp.Except(sjp).ToList();

    var ToRemove = firstJsonObj.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().Where(x => !result.Contains(((JProperty)x).Path))
    .Where(x => !(((JProperty)x).Value.Type == JTokenType.Object || ((JProperty)x).Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)).ToList();

    for (var i = ToRemove.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (secondJsonObj.SelectToken(ToRemove[i].Path).Type == ToRemove[i].Value.Type)
            ToRemove[i].Remove();
    }

    ExceptValues(firstJsonObj, secondJsonObj);
    var fvl = firstJsonObj.Properties().ToList();
    for (var j = fvl.Count() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {

        if (fvl[j].Value.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            if (fvl[j].Value.Count() == 0) fvl[j].Remove();
        }
        else if (fvl[j].Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            if (((JObject)fvl[j].Value).Properties().Count() == 0) fvl[j].Remove();
        }
    }

    return firstJsonObj;
}

public static void ExceptValues(JObject firstJsonObj, JObject secondJsonObj)
{
    var firstValues = GetValues(firstJsonObj).ToList();
    var secondValues = GetValues(secondJsonObj).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < firstValues.Count(); i++)
    {
        var secondValue = secondValues.Where(x => x["path"] == firstValues[i]["path"]).FirstOrDefault();
        var newItems = firstValues[i]["items"].Distinct().Except(secondValues[i]["items"].Distinct());

        string p = (string)firstValues[i]["path"];

        var fv = (JArray)firstJsonObj.SelectToken(p);

        for (var j = fv.Count() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (fv[j].Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                if (fv[j].Count() > 0) continue;
            }
            else if (fv[j].Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                if (((JObject)fv[j]).Properties().Count() > 0) continue;
            }

            fv[j].Remove();
        }

        foreach (var item in newItems) fv.Add(item);

        if (fv.Count() == 0) firstJsonObj.Remove(fv.Path);
    }
}

public static List<string> GetPropPathes(JObject jsonObj)
{
    return jsonObj.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>()
         .Where(x => !(((JProperty)x).Value.Type == JTokenType.Array
         || ((JProperty)x).Value.Type == JTokenType.Object))
         .Select(x => x.Path).ToList();
}

public static List<JObject> GetValues(JObject jsonObj)
{
    return jsonObj.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JArray>().Select(y => new JObject
    {
        ["path"] = y.Path,
        ["items"] = new JArray(y.Where(x =>
         !(x.Type == JTokenType.Array || x.Type == JTokenType.Object)))
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have one question about your code. When we have array with multiple objects and we compare them, how can you know which to compare with? Asking because seems your code works for that scenario and don't have an idea how.

Comment: @Szyszka947 In array doesn't matter in which order are these objects. Linq Except compares them. but when you instances of clasess , path of each property compares, it is just a string. After this I compare types of the properties with the same path.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about JSON paths. So smart solution. Big thanks :D

Comment: I tried a lot JSONs and found that this code doesn't work in nested array situations. I wonder how this code is supposed to handle multiple nested arrays and objects without using recursion. I read it and I don't understand, could you explain?

Comment: @Szyszka947 This code is raw and  still need a lot of testing.  You have to realize that  this task need to create the whole special library and this code  should grow and grow duirng the testing.  I an not a free coder here and I just gave you an example how I am probably stasrt.  If I would be paid for it , I would ask a month at least  for this project. , As  I told you yesterday, the objects will be ok on any nested level, but since an array   objects doesnt have a name and a fixed positiion they will need much more code to be completed

Comment: @Szyszka947 And about  a recursion. DescendantsAndSelf() functions creates a list of objects including all  the nested objects, doesn't matter how many levels

Comment: @Szyszka947 With value arrays my agorith should work properly but the problem  is how to work with a nested arrays and objects. It is not my fault , and not even my task. A sofware developer will need a specification how to compare diffeent kind of objects that doesnt have a name and type. . If they are egual  if they have absolutely the same properties and absolutely the same nested properties names? in this case the whole object should excluded, not just one property as it is in a named objects.  So there are hundreds questions for BA that is a way out from the pourpose of this project

Comment: People are ready to splend 10-15 min  to create an answer . Nobody will spend days and weeks just helping  you for free.

Comment: Yes I know, I just wanted to point that out for future readers. I was also curious why I don't see recursion anywhere. Thanks again

Comment: @Szyszka947 As I told this algorith will be working ok for objects and nested objects . It can be used for arrays too, but needs some more improvements to make work it properly. Just spend some time with a debugger going from line to line to cath some ideas.